# Advanced Inner Join between User, User_Group and Subscriptions Tables

Tags: mysql, sql, database, select, inner-join

I have Three tables:

```
Users          { id | name | email }
User_Group     { User_id | group_id }
Subscriptions  {user_id, sub_level }
```

- User can be signed to more that User group.
- User can be subscribed to more than subscription plan.

Let's suppose we have:

Table Users:

```
[1, John, john@email.com]

[2, Lara, lara@email.com]
```

Table User Group:

```
[1,6]  // User 1 is assigned to Group 6

[1,3]  // User 1 also assigned to Group 3

[2,3]  // User 2 in ONLY assigned to Group 3
```

Table Subscriptions :

```
[1, 8] // User 1 have subscription level 8

[2, 8] // User 2 have subscription level 8

[2, 9] // Also User 2 have subscription level 9
```

What I want to get is:

All UNIQUE users who are assigned to ONLY group 3 and who have at least one subscription.

What I have tried:

```
SELECT U.Username, U.email, G.group_id, S.sub_level FROM `Users` AS U
INNER JOIN `User_Group` AS G
ON U.id = G.user_id
INNER JOIN `Subscriptions` AS S
ON U.id = S.user_id
WHERE G.group_id = 3
Limit 0,10
```

Problem it will display users who are also assigned to others groups like user 1 who is in group 6 and 3. Also it will display duplicate lines because one user can have many subscription levels.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One method is to use aggregation:

```
SELECT U.Username, U.email, MAX(G.group_id)
FROM `Users` U INNER JOIN
     `User_Group` G
     ON U.id = G.user_id INNER JOIN
     `Subscriptions` S
     ON U.id = S.user_id
GROUP BY  U.Username, U.email
HAVING MAX(G.group_id) = 3 AND MIN(G.group_id) = 3 ; -- condition on groups
```

The condition on subscriptions is handled just by the `join` condition.

This is probably more efficient as:

```
select u.*
from users u
where exists (select 1
              from user_groups ug
              where ug.user_id = u.id and ug.group_id = 3
             ) and
      not exists (select 1
                  from user_groups ug
                  where ug.user_id = u.id and ug.group_id <> 3
                 ) and
      exists (select 1
              from subscriptions s
              where s.user_id = u.id
             );
```

For this query, you want indexes on `user_groups(user_id, group_id)` and `subscriptions(user_id)`.  Actually, these indexes are a good idea for both ways of formulating the query.

Comment: I like the second suggestion. But how did you prevent the return of duplicate users in case when the user has more than one subscription ?

Comment: @iOSGeek . . . I don't understand the comment.  This is selecting from `users`, so there are no duplicate users.

Comment: You are right I missed that part. Your solution works fine. It's accepted.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT
    U.username, U.email,
    G.group_id,
    S.sub_level
FROM
    Users U
INNER JOIN User_Group G ON
    G.user_id = u.id AND
    G.group_id = 3
INNER JOIN Subscriptions S ON S.user_id = U.id
WHERE
    NOT EXISTS
    (
        SELECT *
        FROM User_Group G2
        WHERE G2.user_id = U.user_id AND G2.group_id <> 3
    )
```

Comment: This will not drop out the multiple results for users with more than one subscription.

Comment: @LarryLustig . . . That would be correct behavior based on the question:  "at least one subscription".

Comment: OP states (last para) *"Problem . . .it will display duplicate lines because one user can have many subscription levels."* so I think that's not the desired behavior.

Comment: You'll need to give criteria for which subscription you want returned as part of the data.

Comment: Yes, This answer solve only the first part, it returns all users who are assigned only to group 3 with at least one subscription. But duplicate users when he has more than subscription.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
SELECT U.Username, U.email FROM `Users` AS U
INNER JOIN `User_Group` AS G
ON U.id = G.user_id
INNER JOIN `Subscriptions` AS S
ON U.id = S.user_id
WHERE G.group_id = 3
GROUP BY U.UserName, U.EMail
```

This will join users to all subscriptions and then only to user group 3; then aggregate the results so each user is present only once.

Your original sample showed Group_ID in the output, but it will always be 3.  It also showed Sub_Level in the output but that's meaningless since you want only one row per user regardless of Subcription entries -- what value would you want to see?

If you really want those two columns in the result set you can do:

```
SELECT U.Username, U.email, G.Group_ID, COUNT(S.Sub_Level) FROM `Users` AS U
INNER JOIN `User_Group` AS G
ON U.id = G.user_id
INNER JOIN `Subscriptions` AS S
ON U.id = S.user_id
WHERE G.group_id = 3
GROUP BY U.UserName, U.EMail, G.Group_ID
```

which will give 3 for group level and tell you *how many* subscription records were "compressed" into each result row.  In place of COUNT you can also use MIN or MAX or (since this is MySQL) the GROUP_CONCAT function which will give you a string list of subscription levels separated by commas.

Comment: You are right about the output of group id, it was just for testing, the same for sub_level because one user can have many subs and I want a unique line. Out of curiosity how MYSQL will deal with that ? display the first subscription of the user I guess. Your first suggestion seems to work. I need just some tests and I will accept your answer

Comment: Can you explain please how did you prevent that a User who is assigned to group 3 and group 6 with at least one subscription to be returned ? because I only want users who are assigned to group 3 and NOT to any other group.

Comment: Actually, my answer fails this part of the question.  You should use either of Gordon's solutions, both of which give the correct results.